# triangle equality in manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometry

For a generilized triangle on a manifold, (distance can be regarded as geodesic length)it is well known that for Eucilidean Geometry，the following is true:

Consider a triangle $ABC$, $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$, then $AD\leq \frac{1}{2}(AB+AC)$

what about some other cases in manifolds. according to my knowledge, it is also true in spheres with dimension n. However I did not konw general cases.

Any advice will be appreaciated.

Comment: When you say, "distance can be regarded as geodesic length," do you mean that the distance between two points is the length of a *shortest* path between them?  I ask because two points can be connected by a geodesic that is not shortest, and one can define triangles formed by such geodesics.

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke. Oh, thanks. Sorry for my poor statement, here I means the shortest geodesic

Answer (score 7):

This is not true for sphere; take triangle with $AB=BC=CA=\tfrac23\cdot\pi$.

Your inequality is equivalent to the condition that *distance function from any point is convex*. In particular, it holds in any complete simply connected manifolds with sectional curvature $\le 0$.

Comment: I guess that the key word to get started on this kind of metric property is "CAT(0)" ("non-positive curvature" if you look to book titles). A lot is to be found in most math libraries on this. 

Comment: @Anton Petrunin  Sorry for my statement for this problem, I means the shortest geodesic,your counter example is just$ AB=BC=AC=\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: @yaoxiao, I did not understand your comment. Anyway, in the example  above all the points lie on a great circle, so you have $AB=BC=CA=\tfrac23\cdot\pi$, $DB=DC=\tfrac13\cdot\pi$
and $AD=\pi$.